# Scrolling: Implement scrollbar when when ipad turns to landscape? Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, scroll

My portrait view is good. All of my text boxes and labels are visible in portrait. But when the user turns the ipad into landscape, few of my textfields and labesl go below and I cannot scroll to see them. Can anyone help please!

Comment: if you don't want to reposition them, put them in a `UIScrollView` I guess?

Comment: So its not possible without the scrollview?

Comment: well, if you want it to be scrollable then you need a scrollview, that's what it is, right?

Answer (score 0):

Put all the things that you want to be able to scroll on in a UIScollView.

Comment: Should I pace the scrollview in side the UIViewController?

Comment: Yes, and then  the texteiflds, labels and so on in the scrollview. Remember that the scrollview would not be scrollable until the content inside is larger, than the whole scrollview.

Comment: Can you kindly give me an example if you have? please